# Update Annotations with ADClusterMapView

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkannotationview

I'm using ADClusterMapView to cluster the annotations of facebook places.
I do the update of Places here, but every time erases everything and puts everything back.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    double centerLatitude= mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude;
    double centerLongitude= mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude;
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"search?type=place&center=%f,%f&distance=%d&limit=100&offset=0", centerLatitude, centerLongitude,kDistanceFromCenter] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error.localizedDescription:%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }

        //Pins
        NSMutableArray * annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

            for (NSDictionary * annotationDictionary in [result objectForKey:@"data"]) {
                ADClusterableAnnotation * annotation = [[ADClusterableAnnotation alloc] initWithDictionary:annotationDictionary];
                [annotations addObject:annotation];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"Building KD-Tree…");
                [self.mapView setAnnotations:annotations];
            });
        });
        //End Pins

    }];

}
```

There is a better way to update the Places without deleting everything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the developers of the library. Unfortunately, this is not currently possible. In fact, an issue was created about this subject on [GitHub](https://github.com/applidium/ADClusterMapView/issues/10).